# How to Install Bigdata ecosystem in single node

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig, apache-zookeeper

I want to install Hadoop+Hbase+Hive+Pig+Zookeeper for my development environment.Is it possible in single node..I need your guidance friends..

If it is possible in single server what are the prerequistes for that environment anyone knows guide me..thanks alot

Comment: You need just 1 thing : https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it to learn Hadoop, try [Hortonworks' Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/). Works well under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK that Hadoop+Hbase+Hive+Pig+Zookeeper are installed in one machine.

However, the easies way to install them together is using CDH4. Here is the document of http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Quick-Start/cdh4qs_topic_3_2.html.

There are some differences between Apache Hadoop and CDH4. So which is more suitable depending on your requirement.